# How to return JSON to browser from model class using SignalR and URL call to Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Here's what's going on. I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API web application. I can call API resources via URL. One of these functions get performance monitoring data for a specified amount of time and returns it in JSON once it has completed. However, what I want to do is return

It is IMPORTANT to note that I am working with a the browser and API resources in the model, not with a View. Please don't casually tell me to use Javascript in a View, because there is no view, or tell me to look at the SignalR wiki because the information for ".NET" sections is meant for desktop applications, not web apps. For example, you can't "Console.WriteLine()" to a browser.

To reiterate, I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API to develop an API, and am calling the API via URL in the browser and it is returning JSON. I am attempting to use SignalR to have the app send JSON to the browser, but it is not doing anything at all. Rather, the application simply returns the completed JSON from the controller action with all of the performance data values once the process has completed. In other words, SignalR is not working.

So what I'm trying to do is while the API resource is gathering all the information, SignalR sends JSON to the browser every second so that the client can see what's going on in real time.
What I need to find out is why SignalR isn't sending it, and how I can send information to be displayed in the browser without Javascript, since I'm working from a model class, not from a view.

As you can see, I subscribe to the event using On, and then use Invoke to call the server-side hub method SendToClient.

Please let me know if I'm trying to do is impossible. I have never heard of a "real-time", dynamic API call via URL.

Here is my hub class. It is located in ~/signalr/hubs and is in a file called LiveHub.cs. The method Send is what I am trying to invoke in the method seen in the next code block.

```
namespace PerfMon2.signalr.hubs
{
    public class LiveHub : Hub
    {

        public void SendToClient(List<DataValueInfo> json)
        {
            Clients.showValue(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method from LogDBRepository.cs that includes the SignalR calls.

```
public List<LogInfo> LogTimedPerfData(string macName, string categoryName, string counterName,
                                          string instanceName, string logName, string live, long? seconds)
    {
        iModsDBRepository modsDB = new iModsDBRepository();
        List<MachineInfo> theMac = modsDB.GetMachineByName(macName);

        if (theMac.Count == 0)
            return new List<LogInfo>();

        else if (instanceName == null)
        {
            if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counterName, categoryName, macName) )
            {
                return new List<LogInfo>();
            }
        }
        else if (instanceName != null)
        {
            if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.CounterExists(counterName, categoryName, macName) ||
                !PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instanceName, categoryName, macName))
            {
                return new List<LogInfo>();
            }
        }
        else if (logName == null)
        {
            return new List<LogInfo>();
        }

        // Check if entered log name is a duplicate for the authenticated user
        List<LogInfo> checkDuplicateLog = this.GetSingleLog(logName);
        if (checkDuplicateLog.Count > 0)
        {
            return new List<LogInfo>();
        }

        PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory(categoryName, theMac[0].MachineName);
        if (category.CategoryName == null || category.MachineName == null)
        {
            return new List<LogInfo>();
        }

        List<LogInfo> logIt = new List<LogInfo>();
        if (category.CategoryType != PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance)
        {
            List<InstanceInfo> instances = modsDB.GetInstancesFromCatMacName(theMac[0].MachineName, category.CategoryName);

            foreach (InstanceInfo inst in instances)
            {
                if (!category.InstanceExists(inst.InstanceName))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (inst.InstanceName.Equals(instanceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName,
                                                                        inst.InstanceName, theMac[0].MachineName);

                    //CounterSample data = perfCounter.NextSample();
                    //double value = CounterSample.Calculate(data, perfCounter.NextSample());
                    string data = "";
                    List<UserInfo> currUser = this.GetUserByName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

                    string timeStarted = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

                    //string[] dataValues = new string[(int)seconds];
                    List<string> dataValues = new List<string>();

                    var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/PerfMon2/");
                    hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    var perfMon = hubConnection.CreateProxy("LiveHub");
                    // perfMon.On("sendValue", message => Console.WriteLine(message));
                    perfMon.On("showValue", json => Console.WriteLine(json));
                    hubConnection.Start().Wait();

                    List<DataValueInfo> lol = new List<DataValueInfo>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
                    {
                        data = "Value " + i + ": " + perfCounter.NextValue().ToString();
                        //dataValues[i] = data;
                        dataValues.Add(data);
                        lol.Add(new DataValueInfo
                        {
                            Value = perfCounter.NextValue().ToString()
                        });
                        //           perfMon.Invoke<List<DataValueInfo>>("Send", lol);
                        perfMon.Invoke("SendToClient", lol);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    string timeFinished = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

                    Log log = new Log
                    {
                        LogName = logName,
                        CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                        InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                        CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                        MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                        TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                        TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                        PerformanceData = string.Join(",", dataValues),
                        UserID = currUser[0].UserID
                    };
                    this.CreateLog(log);
                    logIt.Add(new LogInfo
                    {
                        LogName = logName,
                        CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                        InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                        CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                        MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                        TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                        TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                        PerformanceData = dataValues.ToList<string>()
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PerformanceCounter perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName,
                                                                        "", theMac[0].MachineName);


            string data = "";
            List<UserInfo> currUser = this.GetUserByName(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            string timeStarted = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

            //string[] dataValues = new string[(int)seconds];
            List<string> dataValues = new List<string>();

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/PerfMon2/");
            hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            var perfMon = hubConnection.CreateProxy("LiveHub");
            // perfMon.On("sendValue", message => Console.WriteLine(message));
            perfMon.On("showValue", json => Console.WriteLine(json));
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();

            List<DataValueInfo> lol = new List<DataValueInfo>();
            for (int i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
            {
                data = "Value " + i + ": " + perfCounter.NextValue().ToString();
                //dataValues[i] = data;
                dataValues.Add(data);
                lol.Add(new DataValueInfo
                {
                    Value = perfCounter.NextValue().ToString()
                });
     //           perfMon.Invoke<List<DataValueInfo>>("Send", lol);
                perfMon.Invoke("SendToClient", lol);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            string timeFinished = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm:ss tt");

            Log log = new Log
            {
                LogName = logName,
                CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                PerformanceData = string.Join(",", dataValues),
                UserID = currUser[0].UserID
            };              
            this.CreateLog(log);
            logIt.Add(new LogInfo
            {
                LogName = logName,
                CounterName = perfCounter.CounterName,
                InstanceName = perfCounter.InstanceName,
                CategoryName = perfCounter.CategoryName,
                MachineName = perfCounter.MachineName,
                TimeStarted = timeStarted,
                TimeFinished = timeFinished,
                PerformanceData = dataValues.ToList<string>()
            });
        }
        return logIt;
    }
```

Here is the controller for the method in LogController.cs :

```
 [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public List<LogInfo> Log_Perf_Data(string machine_name, string category_name, string counter_name, string instance_name,
                                   string log_name, long? seconds, string live, string enforceQuery)
    {
        LogController.CheckUser();

        // POST api/log/post_data?machine_name=&category_name=&counter_name=&instance_name=&log_name=&seconds=
        if (machine_name != null && category_name != null && counter_name != null && log_name != null && seconds.HasValue && enforceQuery == null)
        {
            List<LogInfo> dataVal = logDB.LogTimedPerfData(machine_name, category_name, counter_name, instance_name,
                                   log_name, live, seconds);
            logDB.SaveChanges();
            return dataVal;

        }

        return new List<LogInfo>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can implement it in push technique. Here is how I do it:
Class with message

```
 public class Message
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The name who will receive this message.
        /// </summary>
        public string RecipientName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The message content.
        /// </summary>
        public string MessageContent { get; set; }
    }
```

Class that will represent client:

```
public class Client
    {
        private ManualResetEvent messageEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private Queue<Message> messageQueue = new Queue<Message>();

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called by a sender to send a message to this client.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">the new message</param>
        public void EnqueueMessage(Message message)
        {
            lock (messageQueue)
            {
                messageQueue.Enqueue(message);

                // Set a new message event.
                messageEvent.Set();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called by the client to receive messages from the message queue.
        /// If no message, it will wait until a new message is inserted.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>the unread message</returns>
        public Message DequeueMessage()
        {
            // Wait until a new message.
            messageEvent.WaitOne();

            lock (messageQueue)
            {
                if (messageQueue.Count == 1)
                {
                    messageEvent.Reset();
                }
                return messageQueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }
```

Class to send messages to clients:

```
public class ClientAdapter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The recipient list.
        /// </summary>
        private Dictionary<string, Client> recipients = new Dictionary<string,Client>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Send a message to a particular recipient.
        /// </summary>
        public void SendMessage(Message message)
        {
            if (recipients.ContainsKey(message.RecipientName))
            {
                Client client = recipients[message.RecipientName];

                client.EnqueueMessage(message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by a individual recipient to wait and receive a message.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The message content</returns>
        public string GetMessage(string userName)
        {
            string messageContent = string.Empty;

            if (recipients.ContainsKey(userName))
            {
                Client client = recipients[userName];

                messageContent = client.DequeueMessage().MessageContent;
            }

            return messageContent;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Join a user to the recipient list.
        /// </summary>
        public void Join(string userName)
        {
            recipients[userName] = new Client();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Singleton pattern.
        /// This pattern will ensure there is only one instance of this class in the system.
        /// </summary>
        public static ClientAdapter Instance = new ClientAdapter();
        private ClientAdapter() { }
    }
```

Sending messages:

```
    Message message = new Message
                                      {
                                          RecipientName = tbRecipientName.Text.Trim(),
                                          MessageContent = tbMessageContent.Text.Trim()
                                      };

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.RecipientName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.MessageContent))
                {
                    // Call the client adapter to send the message to the particular recipient instantly.
                    ClientAdapter.Instance.SendMessage(message);
}
```

Receive messages (this is JavaScript functions written in test page. They render content of the message on ASPX page. Here you should implement your logic):

```
 // This method will persist a http request and wait for messages.
        function waitEvent() {

            CSASPNETReverseAJAX.Dispatcher.WaitMessage("<%= Session["userName"] %>", 
            function (result) {

                displayMessage(result);

                // Keep looping.
                setTimeout(waitEvent, 0);
            }, function () {

                // Keep looping.
                setTimeout(waitEvent, 0);
            });
        }

        // Append a message content to the result panel.
        function displayMessage(message) {
            var panel = document.getElementById("<%= lbMessages.ClientID %>");

            panel.innerHTML += currentTime() + ": " + message + "<br />";
        }

        // Return a current time string.
        function currentTime() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            return currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
        }
```